# How to pass a list of objects to a thread function

Tags: python, multithreading

I have to pass a list of objects to a function that executes in a thread in python. I need to be able to call functions of those objects, such as `animal.bite()`. I created a generic test class:

```
class test_class:    
    def f(self):
        print 'hello'
```

and created a list of these objects:

```
test_object = test_class()
new_object = test_class()
strlist = [test_object, new_object]
```

and have a function that creates a thread if one hasn't already been created:

```
def threadScheduler(*stringlist):
    global lock #variable defined elsewhere, makeshift resource lock
    if not lock:
        print "creating thread"
        lock = True
        thread = threading.Thread(name='heartbeat', target=threadWorkLoad, args=(stringlist,))
        thread.start()
```

This is the function `threadWorkLoad`:

```
def threadWorkLoad(*stringlist):
    global lock
    for item in stringlist:
        print 'in thread', item.f()
    time.sleep(2)
    lock = False
    return
```

and this is the main loop:

```
for x in range(0,10):
    print 'in main thread', strlist[0].f()
    threadScheduler(strlist)
    time.sleep(1)
```

What I would like to do is to be able to call the function `f()` on the objects in the list in `threadWorkLoad`, but currently I get the error `AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'f'`

If I replace those objects with strings, the code works the way I want it to. But I need to be able to do the same thing with objects. How do I do this in python?

EDIT:

Some other things I tried -

I changed the creation of the thread in `threadScheduler` to `thread = threading.Thread(name='heartbeat', target=threadWorkLoad, args=[stringlist])` with no luck.

I also tried to put in the following statement as the first line of `threadScheduler`:

`print 'in scheduler', stringlist[0].f()`

and I get the same error. It seems like the issue is related to passing a list objects as a function parameter.

I should also clarify that we are using Python 2.5.2.

Comment: Is the comma after stringlist in `thread = threading.Thread(name='heartbeat', target=threadWorkLoad, args=(stringlist,))` intentional?  I expect it has something to do with your problem.

Comment: @ScottMermelstein Yes, I came across that in another question. Although I've also tried replacing `args=(stringlist,)` with `args=[stringlist]` and I get the exact same error. In fact, I've tried something else (i'll modify my OP to show you what) and that didn't work either, so I'm quite sure that isn't the cause of the issue.

Comment: One other thing to try: instead of `args=(stringlist,)` or `args=[stringlist]`, try `args=tuple(stringlist)`.  The problem is the way you're setting up the args.  It expects a tuple of arguments, while you're attempting to pass it a 1-tuple with a list as the only member of that tuple.

Comment: @ScottMermelstein That did it, along with a little change I made in the main loop when calling threadScheduler - I had to pass `*strlist` not just `strlist`

Comment: Cool, glad to solve the problem.  You might want to self-answer it, that way others will see an answer without having to read the comments. (I'm too lazy to write it up, and I wasn't aware of the *strlist part, so it would be good for you to explain it.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two changes had to be made for this to work (thanks to Scott Mermelstein):

In the main loop, `threadScheduler(strlist)` had to be changed to `threadScheduler(*strlist)`. I verified this by adding the following line to the `threadScheduler()` function:

```
print 'in scheduler', stringlist[0].f()
```

and was able to successfully call `f()` only after I added the asterisk. I'm unsure of why the argument had to be passed this way, though.

Additionally, I had to change

```
thread = threading.Thread(name='heartbeat', target=threadWorkLoad, args=(stringlist,))
```

to

```
thread = threading.Thread(name='heartbeat', target=threadWorkLoad, args=tuple(stringlist))
```

Then I was able to successfully call `f()` for each object in the list in the `threadWorkLoad()` function.